# How to fill a null field expression with dataset values using access and vs 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-access, dataset, ms-access-2007, rdlc

[image]

The code works if i pass a specific parameter say "India".But when nulll value is passed exception is thrown. I came to the conclution that its coz of null field expression but do not know how to fill field with datasource.
[image]

I have allowed null and blank values but still error persists.as im trying to duplicate northwind database, i could see it was working.Im adding a screenshot of northwind code which works, (field value  contains Dataset!!).[image]

Please tell me how to add datasource to field expression.